# How to write regular matching expression. -Java

Tags: java, pattern-matching

I want to write matching expression to read string between parentheses () from a big string. eg: the big string is:-

```
(something), (something2), (something3)
```

How can I write matching expression for this to read something, something2, something3 in groups.

Comment: can `somethings` contain parens?

Comment: no, it doesn't contain braces.

Comment: @Harsh Perhaps you should look at my answer - it reads the somethings into a String[] in just one line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read all those groups in one go but using `Matcher#find()` and this expression you might read those: `\(([^\(\)]*)\)` (reads: match must start with `(`, must contain any number of characters not being `(` or `)` - those form your group - , and must end with `)` ).

Note that the escape in the brackets is not necessary, but done for consistency, since they are needed outside.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\(\\)]*)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher( "(something), (something2), (something3)" );

while(m.find())
{
  System.out.println(m.group( 1 ));
}
```

This prints:

```
something
something2
something3
```

Comment: It returns `(something)\n
(something1)\n
(something2)\n
(something3)` (`\n\` used for display purposes).

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - I don't quite get your comment. The regex won't return the parentheses, just the group in between.

Comment: @Thomas, you specified a `group(1)` while I used `group()`, which returned the result as you see on my post. It actually solved my Regular expression issue. :-)

Comment: @Thomas - yes you *can* read it all in one line! See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can read all the somethings into an array with one line:

```
String[] somethings = input.replaceAll("(^.?*\\(|\\)[^\\(]*$)", "").split("\\).*?\\(");
```

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    String input = "foo (something1) (something2), blah (something3) bar";
    String[] somethings = input.replaceAll("(^[^\\(]*\\(|\\)[^\\(]*$)", "").split("\\).*?\\(");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(somethings));
}
```

Output:

```
[something1, something2, something3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following program will get required output

```
public class RegexTestStrings {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "(something),(something2),(something3)";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] splitString = (EXAMPLE_TEST.split("\\("));
        System.out.println(splitString.length);
        for (String string : splitString) {
            System.out.println(string.replace(")",""));
        }
    }
}
```

First, it split all starting with `(` and after that replace `)` to `""` so you will get output as:

```
something,

something2,

something3
```